# Print Block heading for $page - section

Tags: theming, blocks

In my `page.tpl.php` I have 2 different sections nl. `$page['section_orange']` and `$page['section_contact']`.

What I want is for my `block.tpl.php` to print my heading in `h2` when a block is listed in the `$page['section_orange']` section and in `h4` in the `$page['section_contact']` section.

How can I achieve this from within my `block.tpl.php` template.
Or do I need to create a hook within my `template.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create template file with name `block--section_contact.tpl.php`, put there code from default `block.tpl.php` file, replace h2 tag by h4 and all blocks in section_contact region will have h4 heading.